# How can I pass through the 'webservice credentials' to my webservice endpoint?

Tags: java, spring-ws

I have a `PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping`, with the `Wss4jSecurityInterceptor` and a custom `CallbackHandler` which does the authentication for me. The requirement now is to pass through the webservice credentials or at least the `UsernameToken` to the webservice to handle a specific use-case.

How can I achieve this? Is it possible to push something to the `MessageContext` and get it later back from there? Or can I retrieve them from the `SoapMessage` Any hints for me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a `UserPasswordAuthenticationToken` and set user details over `#setDetails(Object details)` of the authentication. The authentication can then be set via

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Later this can be retrieved from the `SecurityContextHolder` normally implemented with a thread local.